undetected_chrome_driver headless mode triggers captcha
I'm trying to scrape TikTok with undetected Chrome driver, my code works fine in the browser but when headless = True, TikTok sends a captcha my way. I read a little bit and heard that it's way easier for websites to detect bots in headless mode but I was wondering if there's some way around that as running the Selenium with the browser is not ideal cause I'm thinking of running my script on an old laptop.
Thanks in advance any help is appreciated.
